# Filter Datatable dynamic/multiple condition using linq or c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have datatable dtResult and it's columns are

```
BuildSequence,
Build#, 
BOptions,
BJob, 
LogID BType, 
BTypeKey, 
BComponentName, 
BCKey, 
RName, 
Rkey, 
RDescrip, 
RStatus, 
BuildMatchExp,
VPart, 
PNumber, 
SName, 
SKey, 
OName, 
OKey, 
Date
```

Now i have few filters, these filters are created dynamically and then user can select those filters. These filters are the columns names of dtResult. I have list of selected filters and list contains the FilterName and Its Value. my question is based on Selected filters how i can filter dtResult? As these filters are not constant they are changing every time. Changing every time i mean users are allowed to select any Filter.

e.g; in one situation user can select BTypeKey and/or BCKey and/or Rkey in-short they can select any filter or no filter.

Now i can filter dResult based on "Fixed" Column but i am not sure how i can do filtration on dynamic filters? Or How i can use linq to do it?

Any Help will be really appreciated, as i am struggling with it.

At code side so far i have just FilterList as this

```
FilterParameters filterlist = new FilterParameters(); 
filterlist.Add(new FilterParameter(this._BuildSequence, this._BuildSequenceName, FilterParameterTypes.Guid, FilterComparisonTypes.BuildSequence)); 
filterlist.Add(new FilterParameter(this._BCKey, this._BComponentName, FilterParameterTypes.Guid, FilterComparisonTypes.BCKey)); 
filterlist.Add(new FilterParameter(this._BTypeKey, base.BTypeName, FilterParameterTypes.Guid, FilterComparisonTypes.BTypeKey)); 
return filterlist;
```

Thanks

Comment: have you done a google search on `C# DataTable Filter`
[MSDN DataTable.Select Method()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @MethodMan Yes i did, but my problem still comes in Dynamic vs Fixed. Like how i will make expression for filtration. Guidance will be appreciated

Comment: can you show some code as to what you are currently doing.. and I am quite sure that this can be done by using variables.. if not then I would suggest creating a stored procedure that implements / utilizes the `ISNULL` checks and you can build your query / filtering that way I wonder if you could also do this by creating an `enum` and passing the variables by getting the string name of the enum.. I would need to see what you are currently trying to see if what I am suggesting would work..

Comment: Currently i am passing these filters to stored procedures but situation is there are 4 different version of SQL running and i am not sure my stored procedures will work on SQL2000 but these are working on SQL2005 and above thats why i was switching it to code. Currently i am passing filters as StoredProcedures parameters with Default as Null in stored Procedure.

Comment: At code side so far i have just 
FilterList as this FilterParameters filterlist = new FilterParameters();
               filterlist.Add(new FilterParameter(this._BuildSequence, this._BuildSequenceName, FilterParameterTypes.Guid, FilterComparisonTypes.BuildSequence));
               filterlist.Add(new FilterParameter(this._BCKey, this._BComponentName, FilterParameterTypes.Guid, FilterComparisonTypes.BCKey));
               filterlist.Add(new FilterParameter(this._BTypeKey, base.BTypeName, FilterParameterTypes.Guid, FilterComparisonTypes.BTypeKey));
                return filterlist;

Answer (score 0):

I think the way I'd approach this would be to have Filter objects that act on the IQueryable returned by the base query. Then map the Filter objects to the filters selected by users.

For instance:

```
class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    public string Foreame { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

abstract class PersonFilter
{
    public abstract IQueryable<Person> Filter(IQueryable<Person> query, string value);
}

class PersonForenameFilter : PersonFilter
{
    public override IQueryable<Person> Filter(IQueryable<Person> query, string value)
    {
        return query.Where(t => t.Foreame == value);
    }
}

class PersonAgeFilter : PersonFilter
{
    public override IQueryable<Person> Filter(IQueryable<Person> query, string value)
    {
        return query.Where(t => t.Age.ToString() == value);
    }
}
```

Then you can create a mapping using say a Dictionary between a friendly label selectable by the user and the Filter object. Then you just do:

```
string filterValue = "Dave";
var someFilter = new PersonForenameFilter();
var baseQuery = dbContext.People;
var filteredQuery = someFilter.Filter(baseQuery, filterValue);
```

Where someFilter is actually retrieved from your mapping dictionary.

Also, note that this is composable so you could apply more than one filter.

Comment: I am working winforms not MVC sorry i didnt mention it earlier. My datatable is result of stored procedure its not a model (model class).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MethodMan, your DataTable.Select Method did work and i converted my Filterlist to expression by using

```
var a = filterList.GroupBy(g => g.ParameterName).Select(gr => 
    string.Format("{0}={1}", gr.First().ParameterName, string.Join(",", gr.Select(g => g.Value))));
var b = string.Join(" And ", a.ToArray());
```

However, I am still stick to passing SQL Parameters to a stored procedure because one of the parameters is csv (and i have used `Split` for csv at database end) and expression for `Select` method has to be like `ID=1` and `Name='abc'` and `Address='here'` and `city='there'` but if you want `Name` to be 'abc' or 'xyz' you need ".. and `Name='abc'` or `Name='xyz'` but its comma separated value for me like `Name={'abc,xyz'}` and I wasn't able to convert `Name` to `Name='abc'` or `Name='xyz'`.